# ¿Cuál es la funcionalidad de border-width y border-color en CSS?

Tags: css

Estoy programando una web y ya logré hacer lo que quería viendo un vídeo de youtube. El asunto es este: no logro entender bien qué es lo que estoy haciendo en cuanto a las propiedades de `border-width`. Tengo este código css:

```
.ses{
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   bottom: 0;
   border-width: 9vh 0 0 100vw;
   border-style: solid;
   border-color:  transparent transparent transparent ghostwhite;
}
```

Ese `div` vacío lo que me genera es una diagonal en el padre para hacer que se vea el efecto de recortado en diagonal. Entiendo que el `border-style` es sólido XD y que tengo 3 colores transparentes, que es lo que me deja ver el fondo gris que ya tengo en el padre. Y tengo uno más que es el color blanco, que es el que genera el efecto de corte.

Ya busqué en la documentación pero no encuentro nada específico cuando le das 4 valores al `border-width` o al `border-color`. Entonces...

¿Será que alguien me puede explicar qué esta pasando? (ya modifiqué los valores y sí hay diferencia, pero no logro entender qué hace)

```
.fondo-barra{
    background-color: #303030;
    position: relative;
    height: 25vh;
}
```

Ese es el padre.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tanto para `border-width` como para `border-color` cuando le pasas cuatro **parámetros** estás indicando que cada uno de ellos hace referencia a uno de los lados del "cuadrado" (empezando por arriba y en sentido de las agujas del reloj).

Por lo que la regla `border-width: 9vh 0 0 100vw;` asigna un grosor de borde de **9vh** para el borde **superior**, **0** para el **derecho**, **0** para el **inferior** y **100vw** para el **izquierdo**.

Sería una manera abreviada de escribir:

```
border-top-width: 9vh;
border-right-width: 0;
border-bottom-width: 0;
border-left-width: 100vw;
```

Con el color sucede lo mismo.

También podrías pasarle **3**, **2** o **1** parámetros, afectando a diferentes lados en cada caso.

**Referencia:** [border-color](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/border-color)